# How to display a bifurcated function definition in exam class?

Tags: exam, alignment

I am a Maths tutor and I have started using LaTeX recently. I am facing a little trouble while displaying a function definition in a question related to continuity. I am using **exam** class and **amsmath** package too.

Here is what I want to achieve -

Q.no.) f(x) = "some expression" followed by spaces and then the condition x <> 0 (this condition should be right aligned)

= "some other expression" followed by spaces and then the condition x=0 (this condition should be right aligned)

Here is my code -

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{Mathematics Test - Continuity}
\maketitle{}

\begin{questions}

\question \textbf{Examine the continuity of the following functions at given points.} \\
\begin{parts}
\part
\begin{flalign*}
f(x) & = \frac{\sin 3x}{x} & x \ne 0 &&\\
& = 3 & x = 0 &&
\end{flalign*}

\end{questions}

\centering \( \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \)

\end{document}
```

This is the output I am getting -

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the first line where f(x) is mentioned, does not start on the line where the question number is mentioned, but starts on the **next** line.

Can anyone pls advise how to rectify this ? Thanks in advance ! - Shankar

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a  short, but complete, code, not just a snippet?

Comment: As @Bernard noticed it is a good use to post a MWE, rather than a snippet, especially for unusual classes/packages.

Comment: Sure.. I have updated the question with full code now.

Comment: If you're using lot of maths in your TeX you should also consider using the package [`mathtools`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) (which contains `amsmath`) that is and extension to `amsmath`!

Answer (score 1):

Using `aligned` like so:

```
\(
\begin{aligned}[t]
.
.
.
\end{aligned}
\)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question \textbf{Examine the continuity of the following functions at given points.} \\
\begin{parts}
\part
\(
\begin{aligned}[t]
f(x) & = \frac{\sin 3x}{x} &\qquad x \ne 0 &&\\
& = 3 & x = 0 &&
\end{aligned}
\)
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. It works.. Thanks a lot @Milo. Although, now, the conditions on x do not get right aligned, but at least they are well-spaced out..

Comment: Further, as I realized just now, I need to also put up a brace to the right of the x conditions - spanning both lines - and write a text "at x = 0" ahead of it. How to do that ? Sorry for missing this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Package `mathtools` provides the `dcases` environment (cases in `displaystyle`), that you can use in-line:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{Mathematics Test - Continuity}
\maketitle{}

\begin{questions}

\question \textbf{Examine the continuity of the following functions at given points.}\medskip
\begin{parts}
\part

$f(x) = \begin{dcases}
\frac{\sin 3x}{x} & x \ne 0 \\
 3 & x = 0
\end{dcases}$
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\centering \( \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. This also looks good. Will play around it.